# mongo-express isn't listing my database

Tags: mongodb

I have a setup with two databases, "admin" and "local". I'm using mongo-express with this config, but only seeing my admin database:

```
'use strict';

var url = require('url');

if (typeof process.env.MONGODB_PORT === 'string') {
  var mongoConnection = url.parse(process.env.MONGODB_PORT);
  process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER = mongoConnection.hostname;
  process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT = mongoConnection.port;
}

module.exports = {
  mongodb: {
    server: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER || 'mysite.example.com',
    port: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_PORT || 27017,

    //autoReconnect: automatically reconnect if connection is lost
    autoReconnect: true,
    //poolSize: size of connection pool (number of connections to use)
    poolSize: 4,
    //set admin to true if you want to turn on admin features
    //if admin is true, the auth list below will be ignored
    //if admin is true, you will need to enter an admin username/password below (if it is needed)
    admin: true,


    // >>>>  If you are using regular accounts, fill out auth details in the section below
    // >>>>  If you have admin auth, leave this section empty and skip to the next section
    auth: [
      /*
       * Add the the name, the username, and the password of the databases you want to connect to
       * Add as many databases as you want!
      {
        database: 'test',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
      }
      */
      ],


    //  >>>>  If you are using an admin mongodb account, or no admin account exists, fill out section below
    //  >>>>  Using an admin account allows you to view and edit all databases, and view stats

    //leave username and password empty if no admin account exists
    adminUsername: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME || 'root',
    adminPassword: process.env.ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD || 'myrootpassword',
    //whitelist: hide all databases except the ones in this list  (empty list for no whitelist)
    whitelist: ['admin','local'],
    //blacklist: hide databases listed in the blacklist (empty list for no blacklist)
    blacklist: []
  },

  site: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8081,
    cookieSecret: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_COOKIESECRET || 'cookiesecret',
    sessionSecret: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SESSIONSECRET || 'sessionsecret',
    cookieKeyName: 'mongo-express',
    sslEnabled: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_ENABLED || false,
    sslCert: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_CRT_PATH || '',
    sslKey: process.env.ME_CONFIG_SITE_SSL_KEY_PATH || ''
  },

  //set useBasicAuth to true if you want to authehticate mongo-express loggins
  //if admin is false, the basicAuthInfo list below will be ignored
  //this will be true unless ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME is set and is the empty string
  useBasicAuth: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME !== '',

  basicAuth: {
    username: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME || 'root',
    password: process.env.ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD || 'anawesomepassword'
  },

  options: {
    //documentsPerPage: how many documents you want to see at once in collection view
    documentsPerPage: 10,
    //editorTheme: Name of the theme you want to use for displaying documents
    //See http://codemirror.net/demo/theme.html for all examples
    editorTheme: process.env.ME_CONFIG_OPTIONS_EDITORTHEME || 'rubyblue',

    //The options below aren't being used yet

    //cmdType: the type of command line you want mongo express to run
    //values: eval, subprocess
    //  eval - uses db.eval. commands block, so only use this if you have to
    //  subprocess - spawns a mongo command line as a subprocess and pipes output to mongo express
    cmdType: 'eval',
    //subprocessTimeout: number of seconds of non-interaction before a subprocess is shut down
    subprocessTimeout: 300,
    //readOnly: if readOnly is true, components of writing are not visible.
    readOnly: false
  },

  // Specify the default keyname that should be picked from a document to display in collections list.
  // Keynames can be specified for every database and collection.
  // If no keyname is specified, it defalts to '_id', which is a mandatory feild.
  // For Example :
  // defaultKeyNames{
  //   "world_db":{  //Database Name
  //     "continent":"cont_name", // collection:feild
  //     "country":"country_name",
  //     "city":"name"
  //   }
  // }
  defaultKeyNames: {
    "admin": {},
    "local": {"continent":"North America","country":"USA","city":"Seattle"}
  }
};
```

I launch use `node app.js` and it connects just fine, but I only see my "admin" database when I visit the mongo-express console on my port 8081. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had not created documents in a collection matching the definition specified in defaultKeyNames. Once I made a mapping appropriate to my data, the "local" database appeared in the admin console.

Comment: Hi Ben - if you solved your own problem, then you should accept your own answer; that takes the question off the unanswered list.